# How to make all constructors of a class private and create static factory methods?

Tags: objective-c

In Java, I would do the following:

```
final class Person {

  private Person() { }

  public static Person makeNewPerson() {

    Person p = new Person();
    // any initialization code...

    return p;

  }

}
```

In Objective-C, my first attempt would be:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

// How to hide constructors here?

+ (Person *) makeNewPerson;

@end

@implementation Person

+ (Person *) makeNewPerson
{
  Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
  // setup...

  return p;
}

@end
```

The reason I want to do this is mainly because I will have many instances of this class, and I would like to use a cache to reuse instances instead of allowing the creation of copies.

Thanks!

Comment: You can make the init method throwing exception and create a custom one not exposed in the header. There is no way to create a truly private members in obj-c.

Answer (score 1):

In objective-c is not necessary to create declaration for methods. Create only implementation and is all you need to make method "private".

Private in quotes because there is no way to make truly private methods.